# How to export 4 million data in MySQL?

Tags: terminal, mysql-workbench, mysql, sqlyog

I have a database with one particular table having more than 4 million record entries. I tried downloading whole db it using MySQL workbench as well as command terminal using following command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p password mydb > myfile.sql
```

But, I got only half of the data downloaded. If I ignored that one particular table, then it's working fine. Can anyone suggest me how to download db with tables having more than million entries?

Comment: @N.B. I have edited the question. Can you suggest me what went wrong?

Comment: Alright - for reals now - you didn't post any errors, and you might have no errors reported. Can you try [this solution](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-max-allowed-packet-is-larger-in-mysqldump-than-mysqld-in-my-cnf) and then report back with the result? Basically, increase the value of `max_packet_size` to a larger value and try with your big table included.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for the update. I didn't get any error while going through download process. But unfortunately full data has not been dumped. I will  try your solution...

Comment: I can't say what went wrong but why not try writing a script that dumps the data base in smaller sections?   If you aren't into that try using the --debug and --log-error options.   You might have some corruption in your data base that is causing the program to crash.    Also, look into the data base at the records where it stopped -- the last successful and first non-successful.  I'll bet you find it there.

Comment: What you have shown is the way to do it.  Several million rows is really not that big of a table (at least not for people who have worked with databases with hundreds of millions or billions of rows). Have you verified that you have appropriate disk space to make the SQL dump?

Comment: @MikeBrant I checked with the disk space and its fine.. I tried downloading with script, mysqlyog, sqlworkbench, phpmyadmin. But nothing works. I googled it. But got only the above query as the solution.

Comment: Can you try this: `mysqldump -u root -p --opt --verbose mydb > myfile.sql` and then check if something odd happens with the table in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below lines in the my.cnf and restart

```
[mysqld]
# Performance settings used for import.
delay_key_write=ALL
bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
```

or

```
mysqldump -u root -p --max_allowed_packet=1073741824 --lock-tables=false mydb > myfile.sql
```